# apache server configurations proxy

Tags: configuration, apache2

i have configured my apache instance to delegate requests to a application running on tomcat container.

lets say my URL for tomcat container is

http://localhost:8014/accounts

I want to access this URL from

http://localhost
Now the configuration in vertual host, i have made to access this is

---

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhsot:8014/accounts/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8014/accounts/
```

---

When I am trying to access http://localhost it gives me following text on the page

---

Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.

The proxy server could not handle the request GET/.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: localhsot

---

Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

---

Can some body please describe the solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is really old and probably solved, but I have to ask -- was the typo on localhost an accident?  Does it really say localhSOt (vs localhOSt)?  Since the error matches the config file, it almost seems to be the cause of the problem.  But I didn't investigate very far; I just happened to notice.

Comment: Thanks for your considerations MJB, I had it identified and resolved, Yes that was the problem too. I was having more other different issues with my Apache configurations.

Comment: What was the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

MJB spotted it right away; you've just made a typo in 'localhost'. Take a look at the error message it's throwing you:

> Reason: DNS lookup failure for: **localhsot**

(emphasis mine)

I feel like there's something else missing as well, but it's escaping me. Fix the typo and give it another go, see if it implodes again.